# Web scraping from forum with R, how to remove quote from previous user and navigate to next page?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My assignment is to scrape forum comments from https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/4161836. How can I scrape them without the quoted comments of previous users? Also, to scrape the next page automatically, how can I write a loop for it? Thank you so much for your help.

R function rvest and CSS selector were used. The scraped results contained quotes from previous users. Is there a way to scrape comments without taking the quotes? Or any ways I can remove the quoted content?

For loop, I cant find a way to do it as codes from most online tutorials are not applicable for this case. Instead of url/pageN, the forum goes by number of comments at each page, url/+n. Any recommendation for this?

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(rvest)
url='https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/4161836'
webpage=read_html(url)
description_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.post_text')
description_data <- html_text(description_data_html)
```

My R code produced output like this:

```
I have a pen.
QUOTE(USERNAME @ DATE TIME) I have a pen.I have a pen too.
```

The expected output should be:

```
I have a pen.
I have a pen too.
```

Comment: seems like some conditions are not clear to me esp which sentence to remove, keep etc.

Comment: Akrun, sorry for the confusion. I would like to remove "QUOTE(USERNAME @ DATE TIME) I have a pen." from the second scraped sentence. So that only "I have pen too" is left. Hope this clarifies. :)

Comment: that is a simple case.  If you check string 2, it is a lengthy one.  after that comes `"QUOTE(ycgoh123 @ Dec 30 2016, 09:49 AM) sounds like very hard.`.  Do you delete the previous whole string

Comment: I will need to delete that part of that row. What I need for that row is "How much your Friend have Pledge to get CIMB CC...???" You can get clearer picture, if you look at the webpage, comment no.3. I need to omit the quotation part.